# when do we call a root of an equation a double root or a root of multiplicity of n?

Tags: functions, polynomials

according to the The fundamental theorem of algebra, a non constant polynomial of degree n with complex coefficients have n Roots, thats allow us to define the multiplicity of some roots so we reach n root for polynomials which have less then n roots, my question is what about other function ? is this true only for polynomials ? for example $(x-1)ln(x)=0$ solving this gives $x=1$ two times, do we call this solution a double root ? and theres other examples like $sin(x)=1$  do we call  $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ a double root on the interval $[0;\pi]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $1$ is a double root of $f(x)=(x-1)\log x$, because not only we have $f(1)=0$, has we also have $f'(1)=0$. But it is not a triple root, since $f''(1)\ne0$.

And $\frac\pi2$ is a double root of $f(x)=\sin(x)-1$, since $f\left(\frac\pi2\right)=f'\left(\frac\pi2\right)=0$. But, again, it is not a triple root, since $f''\left(\frac\pi2\right)\ne0$.

Comment: @Arthur I've edited my answer. Thank you.